# Build New Joomla Component

Tags: joomla, components

I have create new joomla component and I have a problem with menu item for my new component.
In local my component is work correctly, but when I uploaded to server my component did not appear in menu item.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, when you uploaded it to the server the link is not showing on the administrator side or front-end?
Did you install the component or just uploaded?
Is database same on you local computer and server?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably missing a record for you component in jos_components table in database on the server.

Having record in jos_components will make link in Back End -> Main Menu -> Components -> You Component

Modify the query below and execute run in it on the server's database.

```
INSERT INTO jos_components (`name`, `link`, `menuid`, `parent`, `admin_menu_link`, `admin_menu_alt`, `option`, `ordering`, `admin_menu_img`, `iscore`, `params`, `enabled`)
VALUES ('You Component name', 'option=com_mycomp', '0', '0', 'option=com_mycomp', 'Menu Text', 'com_search', '0', 'js/ThemeOffice/component.png', '0', '', '1');
```

Answer (score -1):

please use this joomla **[tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1)** to get a complete reference of how to create joomla component

Comment: This is way off... You can just give links to home page of PHP, c#, mysql, etc... and say read all that to figure out your problem... He has developed component, it's just little problem with link.

Comment: I only want him to check and follow the component installation procedure whether its right as in the documentation by joomla community. Also I have not given the link to the root say http://doc.joomla.org or somewhere with a huge reference as you said, for you to criticize, its obvious to have links to some sites to give a reference if we cannot type the whole thing here..  Please go to that link and try to understand what you get from there. I think its not a good way to keep your manners.I am also not expecting any reputation rather for a good connection with all and for everyones well being